# How to search a hybrid ASP.NET Intranet site?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, search, intranet

How would you implement a search facility within an ASP.NET hybrid application? I'm really tempted to start rebuilding our Intranet application using ASP.NET MVC & Web Forms (mainly MVC though).

I know how to search the dynamic content from a database, but I'm struggling with the static content in the Views. Surely this should be an easy task with routing and a sitemap.

Comment: Web forms & MVC, all ASP.NET though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [Lucene](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/library/IntroducingLucene.aspx)

Once setup correctly you can crawl all your static url's and use it to create a file based index that can be searched on keywords. It is possible to generate ranked results.

Comment: Thanks Konrad, that looks like something I can use. Thanks again!

Comment: In that case, to further expedite your travels ;) I have included links to resources I found VERY useful using Lucene (and alternatives):

http://www.searcharoo.net OR 

"http://www.theplancollection.com/house-plan-related-articles/search-
using-asp-net-and-Lucene"

OR http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/DotLuceneSearch.aspx

Oh, If you like my answers, an up-vote is appreciated ;)